# Hide my_player frame when changing frames by using 'gotoandplay/stop?

Tags: flash, adobe

**Solved myself. I should have been referring to my_loader instead of my_player**

I've got a stupid thingy.

I've created some kind of 'website' with Flash, using 1 frame per page. on frame 3, i've created a youtube video player by using this code

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

var my_player:Object;

var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
my_loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3")); 
my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);

function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void{
addChild(my_loader);
my_player = my_loader.content;
my_player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady); 
} 

function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void{
my_player.setSize(640,360);
my_player.x = 370;
my_player.y = 200;
my_player.loadVideoById("44LnsBZ3OTc",0);
} 

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVid); 
function playVid(e:MouseEvent):void { 
my_player.playVideo(); 
} 
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVid); 
function pauseVid(e:MouseEvent):void { 
my_player.pauseVideo();
}
```

The problem is: When switching frames (GotoAndPlay(#), it changes frames as it should, but the my_player frames still stays. No matter what I've tried.

Any solutions?

FLA File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/alouv7nxinnbjkp/EindopdrachtPortfolio.fla